# HDR white background

Tags: rendering, scene, hdri

Can i use HDR images, but with background colors? Not transparent.

İ have a scene with a hdr for lights and reflections, but i want background to stay white or other color. İs it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

İ found solution by myself, so if anyone else had this question, here you are

[image: Node setup]

Comment: are you the same person that asked the question? then you should merge your accounts, check how here https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts. Also check [ask] and mark your answer as accepted, but please [edit] to explain what's happening in the screenshot.